# Bad row estimates joining two tables on date range

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, inner-join

### Tables

- TEST_RUNS (ID int, Date_Time datetime, Row1 int, Row2 int, Row3 int, Row4 int)
- ADMIN_TIME_FILTER (ID int, Name varchar(20), Start_Date datetime, End_Date datetime)

**ADMIN_TIME_FILTER** holds a small list of shifting date ranges that get updated frequently via automation.  We have common date ranges (ThisYear, ThisDay, etc) and some more esoteric ranges.  This table exists strictly as a way to filter data out of TEST_RUNS in a join.

**TEST_RUNS** holds actual data we care about, and has millions of rows.  We have a bunch of defined views joining these two tables together, so we can just update the ADMIN_TIME_FILTER table and have the changes propagate to the views.  Aside from date, there are no rows that link these two tables together.

### Queries

The problem is that the estimated row count is widly off, resulting in poor performing queries.  Here's a simple query the exhibits the bad estimate:

```
with test as (
    SELECT a.* FROM TEST_RUNS a
    INNER JOIN ADMIN_TIME_FILTER b ON b.ID = 5 -- ID for ThisYear range
       AND a.date_time BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.end_date
)
select count(*) from test
```

Here's the query plan:

[image: queryplan]

Statistics aren't the problem.  I can run the following query and get an accurate row estimate

```
with test as (
    select tr.* from test_runs tr
    where tr.date_time between '2012-01-01 00:00:00' and '2012-12-31 00:00:00'
)
select count(*) from test
```

### Help

Switching away from our join methodology isn't a simple task, so I'm looking for an alternative to improve the row estimate.

Indexed views don't appear to be a viable option due to the performance implications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the row count.  Your query is set up as a non-equijoin.  There is really no other way for SQL Server to handle the join other than by using nested loops.

If you have an id in the "a" table, the following might help:

```
with test as (
    SELECT a.*
    FROM TEST_RUNS a INNER JOIN
         ADMIN_TIME_FILTER b
         ON a.id = b.id and b.ID = 5 and -- ID for ThisYear range
            a.date_time BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.end_date
)
select count(*) from test
```

By matching on the "id" between the tables, SQL Server can consider other join algorithms, such as merge joins or hash joins.

I suspect that there might be another way to fix this.  What is the index on B using?  I would suggest (id, start_date, end_date).  The engine might be deciding to using an index on the dates to satisfy the query.

Comment: Yes, the non equi-join was what I suspected.  There's no real relation between the tables, so there's no other column I can join them on.  I am using an index with ID, start_date, end_date.

Comment: You could also fix this by changing the ADMIN_TIME_FILTER table.  Instead of having a date range, you would a separate row for each date.  This would make the table much bigger, but the join much more efficient.